# Variable changes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I need to keep my variable in long form, I don't understand these changes.

my code:

```
//DB CONNECTION

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `slevy` WHERE 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sleva = $row['sleva'];
    echo $sleva;
}
echo "------------".$sleva;
```

output is:

```
99381585659209563465667261720583722336659395405------------659395405
```

Comment: you want your variable name like this $1214564888545sleva   right??

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: It's not clear at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the body of cycle you save into `$sleva` and then `echo` all sales, after the `while` cycle `$sleva` contains just the last one row from database.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sleva = $row['sleva'];
    echo $sleva . '<br>';
}
// output like:
993815856<br>
592095634<br>
656672617<br>
205837223<br>
659395405<br>
```

You wrote `to keep variable in long form`. It means, probably, to save into `$sleva` variable the whole string, concatenate all sales.

```
$sleva = '';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sleva .= $row['sleva'];
}

echo $sleva;
// output: 99381585659209563465667261720583722336659395405
```

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing each value you get in while loop separately, so at the end the variable contains only the last value. To assign all those values in one string to the variable, you need to contatenate it like this:

```
$sleva.= $row['sleva'];
```

Also remember to initialize it before the loop:

```
$sleva = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `$sleva` to contain the whole string use `$sleva .= $row['sleva'];` to add "content" to the variable. In your code, every iteration of the `while` loop sets `$sleva` with new content.